# Angular2 - Unresolved Router Import

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am building an ionic2 application and I have been following the Heroes example on the ionic framework official website but have been having hard times importing the router directives.

```
    import { provideRouter, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';

    export const routes: RouterConfig = [
    { path: 'crisis-center', component: CrisisCenterComponent },
    { path: 'heroes', component: HeroListComponent },
    { path: 'hero/:id', component: HeroDetailComponent }];                                

    export const APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS = [
    provideRouter(routes)
];
```

The error which this piece of code produces is:

> **Unresolved provideRouter**
>
> **Unresolved RouterConfig**
>
> **Cannot resolve directory @angular**

Any ideas why this might be?

The package.json file looks like this:

```
 {
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-beta.10",
    "ionic-native": "1.2.4",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "del": "2.2.0",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-watch": "4.3.5",
    "ionic-gulp-browserify-typescript": "2.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-fonts-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-html-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-sass-build": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-scripts-copy": "^2.0.0",
    "run-sequence": "1.1.5"
  },
  "name": "test",
  "description": "test: An Ionic project",
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "cordova-plugin-device",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
  ],
  "cordovaPlatforms": []
}
```

After I manually inserted the router dependency as suggested by @MatWiligora, I got the following error when I tried to do **npm install**

```
    npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency @angular/core@^2.0.0-rc.4 included from @angular/router will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency @angular/compiler@^2.0.0-rc.4 included from @angular/router will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency @angular/common@^2.0.0-rc.4 included from @angular/router will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency @angular/platform-browser@^2.0.0-rc.4 included from @angular/router will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
npm WARN peerDependencies The peer dependency @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@^2.0.0-rc.4 included from @angular/router will no
npm WARN peerDependencies longer be automatically installed to fulfill the peerDependency
npm WARN peerDependencies in npm 3+. Your application will need to depend on it explicitly.
```

and

```
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.4.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.3 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/router@3.0.0-beta.2 wants @angular/common@^2.0.0-rc.4
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-browser@2.0.0-rc.3 wants @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.3
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0-rc.3 wants @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.3
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer ionic-angular@2.0.0-beta.10 wants @angular/common@^2.0.0-rc.3

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!  npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Can you share your package.json?

Comment: @Sanket I have included the package.json above!

Comment: you are missing @angular/router in dependencies. Please update as mentioned in below answer.

Comment: @Sanket Thanks! Is there any shortcut command to update it?

Comment: angular2 is a s*it... so much dependency issue and it's being updated so rapidly

Comment: hi @user3153278 are you able to ingetrate angular2 router to ionic2?? Can you share code and example with us?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you are installing **"@angular/router":  "3.0.0-beta.2"** as your dependency in package.json, that is the current version of the router.

Also did you inject: **APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS** to your bootstrap ?

Comment: @MatValigora I have included the json file in my post above. Also, when I am trying to inject APP_Router_PROVIDERS I am unable to do that also, as my import of the APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS says UNRESOLVED APP_ROUTER_PROVIDERS

Comment: As I said, add: "@angular/router":  "3.0.0-beta.2" to your dependencies in package.json.

Comment: Thanks! Is a manual insertion going to fix the issue? Shouldn't it be installed via a command that would update the angular2 module inside node_modules too?

Comment: You can insert it manually and then perform npm install through your terminal.

Comment: Add this line **'router',** also to packageNames array  in systemjs.config.js file

Comment: @MatWiligora, I have updated the post by adding additional problems that appeared after manually inserting the dependency and doing npm install. Also, are all these manual insertions necessary or have I done something wrong that wouldn't let me do it otherwise?

Comment: Update, although I got all these errors while doing an npm install again, the dependencies now seem to have been imported. Thanks @MatWaligora!

Comment: Hmm, try running `npm install @angular/router` instead of manually adding it to dependencies then

Comment: Npm, btw try upgrading your angular files to rc-4 :)

Comment: Yeah, I tried doing it that way also, but didn't work. The manual insertion seems to be the only way for now which is a pity. Still not sure why I got the npm install error message though. Nevertheless, the problem now seems to be gone, which is the most important thing for the moment! Many thanks

Comment: Hi @MatWaligora are you able to include angular router in ionic2 project? Can you share a working solution for it??? There are so many people which is searching it. So if you can share some configuration we will very happy!
As you can see here in the ionic forum we are tyring to do this also, but there are some problems with it!
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-updating-the-url-when-pushing-page-on-the-nav-stack/67683

Comment: Hi @user3153278 are you able to include angular router in ionic2 project? Can you share a working solution for it??? There are so many people which is searching it. So if you can share some configuration we will very happy!
As you can see here in the ionic forum we are tyring to do this also, but there are some problems with it!
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/solved-updating-the-url-when-pushing-page-on-the-nav-stack/67683

Comment: Hi Michael, unfortunately I haven't touched Ionic 2 yet, so I don't know if I can help you with this